Trying to understand the angles in $n$-Dimensional sphereical coordinates.
(Originally asked on the physics SE since question arose in the context of a physics problem but was told it might be a better fit here)
I ran into this issue about which angle should be singled out when trying to compute a scattering cross section in QFT; I'll try to come up with the simplest example that highlights what I'm trying to ask. Often we need to perform integrals over all n-dimensional space of the dot product of the integration variable and some fixed vector, such as
$$ \int d^n p\;\; \vec{p}\cdot\vec{k} $$ For some fixed $\vec{k}$ (Or often is some more complex function of $\vec{p}\cdot\vec{k}$ but keeping it simple). The lengths of these vectors are usually constrained in some way so its really only the direction we need to worry about integrating over, and so we usually switch to spherical polar coordinates as
$$ d^n p = p^{n-1}dp\, d\Omega_{n-1}$$  where $p=\lvert \vec{p}\rvert$ and $d\Omega_{n-1}$ is the surface area element of the unit $(n-1)$-Sphere. We can then write $\vec{p}\cdot\vec{k}=p k \cos(\theta)$ to perform the integral as
$$\int dp\; p^n k \int d\Omega_{n-1} \cos(\theta)$$ And here's where my problem with the angles comes in. From breaking down the dot product, that $\theta$ should be the angle between the vectors $\vec{p},\vec{k}$, i.e. the angle between them in the plane that they both lie in. This angle in general doesn't have anything to do with any of the coordinate angles we'd be integrating over in $d\Omega_{n-1}$, lets call those $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_{n-2}$, but since the orientation of our coordinate system is arbitrary we can always choose to rotate our coordinate system such that it does coincide with one of them. The issue then is just which one.
In 3D spherical polar coordinates, we only have a 2-Sphere and two angles, a polar angle (usually $\theta$) off of the $z$-axis in the range $[0,\pi]$ and an azimuthal angle (usually $\varphi$) off the $x$-axis in the $xy$-plane in the range $[0,2\pi)$. My intuition is that we could pick either of these angles to be the $\theta$ coming from the dot product, but we usually pick the polar angle since its easier, we can just line up $\vec{k}$ with the $z$-axis, the ranges of the angles are the same, and then we don't have to worry about the restriction that $\varphi$ needs to be within the plane, which might potentially then require projections to get things to line up correctly (side note: is this intuition wrong?). But then in our general case, we have $n-1$ angles, $n-2$ of them are polar angles (usually the $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_{n-2}$) off of some axes in the range $[0,\pi]$ and the remaining $\phi_{n-1}$ is an azimuthal angle in the plane normal to all the axes in the range $[0,2\pi)$. Again, it feels like we could pick any one of these angles, but using one of the polar ones would be easiest. But why should it then matter which polar angle we choose? Picking different angles does look like it changes the form of the integral, since
$$ d\Omega_{n-1} = \sin^{n-2}(\phi_1) d\phi_1\ldots \sin(\phi_{n-2}) d\phi_{n-2} d\phi_{n-1} $$
So all the integrals over the angles we don't pick just look like integrals of sin to various powers, and the one we do pick looks like $\int \sin^m(\phi_x) \cos(\phi_x) d\phi_x$ where the power of the sin $m$ will also depend on which angle $\phi_x$ we choose. At this point I was still sure the final answer wouldn't matter on which angle we choose, the differences in all the various integrals canceling each other out, so when I was doing the original problem I just choose to use $\phi_{n-2}$ so we have the simplest integral to perform. But doing this, you get the wrong answer; you only get the right answer if you pick $\phi_1$, giving the highest power $m$ and the most complex integrand. Why is this? And I don't mean why don't we get the same answers, I'm sure if I picked through these integrals in full detail in all the different cases I could track down exactly what in the maths is resulting in the different choices giving different results, I mean that given that they do give different answers (even just from the fact that choosing to use $\phi_{n-2}$ gave the wrong answer for the problem I was doing), and assuming that I didn't make a mistake in the computations, the only thing that could be the source of the error is the assumption in the beginning that we could choose to rotate our coordinate system to line $\vec{k}$ up with any of the axes off of which we measure the polar angles, thus aligning the angle between $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{p}$ with that polar angle. Why is this assumption wrong? Why can we only choose to line it up with the first angle? Have I just misunderstood something fundamental about spherical coordinates? Is it that only the first polar angle is just a straight angle off an axis and all the others have some sort of restriction to them, so we'd have to project out the angle between the vectors to use them, like if we wanted to use the azimuthal angle in 3D?

You know this? Over which region do you integrate $\vec{p},?$

@KurtG. Yes that's the page I took most of this from - Using those coordinate definitions is what I mean when I say I'm sure I could pick through the integrals in full detail and find where in the maths the difference is coming from.
The integration is over all $n$-space, using the usual physics shorthand that $\int = \int_{-\infty}^\infty$, I just left it out as I didn't think the region of integration was relavent to my question about understanding the various angles.

Over all $n$-space the integral $\int d^n p;; \vec{p}\cdot\vec{k}$ does not exist. I'd recommend to take the cases $n=3$ and $n=4$ and work on a few explicit examples. Most of your questions should then answer themselves.

@KurtG. Yes of course, the integral as I've written it is divergent, but I'm taking this as the simplest case to try to understand the angles, in reality the integrand would be a more complicated function of the dot product. I'm just trying to understand why my assumption that we could align the angle between the vectors with any coordinate angle is wrong, that assumption doesn't depend on the bounds or the functional form of the integrand. I can see why the math gives different answers looking at cases, but I'm trying to build an intuition about why the assumption is wrong in the first place.

You won't get the full understanding before having worked out  a handful of concrete low dimensional examples to the point of seeing the final numbers. Forget the intuition and stop staring at formulas.

Ok so I'm just posting an answer myself for anyone wondering this in the future. As pointed out by Reddit user u/Equal_Veterinarian22 in this comment, the issue is down to my misunderstanding how the angles are defined. It's not the case that all the polar angles are angles off some axes with the azimuthal angle being in a plane normal to all of them; rather only the first polar angle is the angle off an axis, the second is an angle in the $(n-1)$ hyperplane normal to this axis, the third in the $(n-2)$ hyperplane normal to both of these, etc onwards until the last angle, the azimuthal angle, is in the plane normal to all others. Thus only the first polar angle gives the right answer since all the other angles would require some projections or similar to write things in terms of them.
